# In Body Harvest, what's the difference between Hero and Easy

Tags: body-harvest

In the N64 game Body Harvest, there are two 'difficulty modes', Hero and Easy. What is the actual difference between these two modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [The Cutting Room Floor](https://tcrf.net/Body_Harvest), the European version's easier mode is called "Zero" and only allows you to complete the first 4 levels.

As for the mechanical differences, it's not entirely clear. The only detail I could find is in the submission comments of the 2004-07-30 speedrun of the game by 'marshmallow', [found here as of the time of this answer](http://speeddemosarchive.com/BodyHarvest.html), which remark,

> I first attempted a BH run in "Hero" mode but soon abandoned the idea as the challenge in Java became too great - I had to slow down significantly just to stay alive. Also, the rate of harvesting seemed faster and I found myself facing mutants much earlier than in normal (which the game calls easy - how do you have hard and easy without a normal?).